# Square blocks for currency, individual numbers

Tags: javascript, php

I'm not sure if there is something out there like the attached image, but wanted to know before I create something from scratch. Must look like the attached image.

Javascript / PHP

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DID you know `HTML`?? The HTML can design such boxes with the help of CSS.

Comment: Yes, but was wanting to know if there is a js library out there that has this sort of thing in the library?